# How to replace binary file in /bin inside a Linux container

Tags: docker, container

I want to make some weird container, one of my tasks were to replace the `uname` binary.
I coded it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
   printf("This is a fake uname\n");
   return 0;
}
```

Compiled it:

```
gcc uname.c -o uname
```

it works fine when I run it on my ubuntu.

I created a `Dockerfile` and copied it to the image:

```
cat > Dockerfile <<EOF
FROM alpine:latest
RUN rm /bin/uname
COPY uname /bin/
ENTRYPOINT sh;
WORKDIR /home
EOF
```

And build it `docker build -t myimage -f Dockerfile .`

when I run the image:

```
docker run -it --rm myimage
```

The file exist but when I try to run it, it writes it doesn't exist:

```
/home # uname
sh: uname: not found
/home # ls -lia uname
ls: uname: No such file or directory
/home # ls -lia /bin/uname
     35 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          8600 Jan 29 13:27 /bin/uname
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you build your binary against `glibc` (as you are using Ubuntu), but then run it on Alpine (which uses `musl` instead).

When you build the binary, some metadata is hardcoded into it, specifically, the *interpreter* (dynamic linker) location. During the binary execution the kernel uses this interpreter to load the binary and all of its runtime dependencies. When you build against `glibc`, the binary requests the `glibc`'s interpreter (something like `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`):

```
$ readelf -l /bin/uname
<...>
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]
```

but there is no such interpreter under Alpine. Alpine has `/lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1` instead, and all its binaries are built so that they request exactly this interpreter:

```
# readelf -l /bin/busybox
<...>
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1]
```

So, when you build your `uname` in Ubuntu and then run it in Alpine, the kernel is unable to find the interpreter, thus it returns "**not found**".

The interesting point is that you may invoke the interpreter manually and this may work if the problem is *only* in the interpreter:

```
# /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1 /bin/uname 
This is a fake uname
```

But this, of course, is only for troubleshooting.

So, what to do?

Your options are either statically link your binary (thus making the interpreter and all shared libraries unneeded so that the kernel may load and run the binary on its own):

```
gcc uname.c -static -o uname
```

or build it under Alpine (maybe try Docker's [multistage builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/)? I would recommend this approach as in this case you explicitly declare your intention and show that you build your custom binary in Alpine to replace the original Alpine's one).

Comment: The `-static` solved it. Thanks you for your informative answer !